# How can I fit a Skellam regression?

Tags: r, statistics, glm, lme4, mixed-models

Is there an easy way to fit a multivariate regression in R in which the dependent variable is distributed in accordance with the [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) (difference between two Poisson-distributed counts)?
Something like:

```
myskellam <- glm(A ~ B + C + D, data = mydata, family = "skellam")
```

This should accommodate fixed effects. But ideally, I would prefer random effects as I understand that fixed effects may introduce measurement biases. Therefore I guess the ideal solution should be using the `lme4` or `glmmADMB` package.

Alternatively, is there a way to transform the data to apply more usual regression tools?

Comment: I would like to point out that the `Skellam` package now has limited regression functionality. See: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264252/is-there-a-reason-why-the-regression-in-the-r-skellam-package-uses-three-optimis

Answer (score 6):

*Incomplete answer, but seems a bit more than a comment.*

Mixed effects seem hard; you could do it with [AD Model Builder](http://admb-project.org) or [Template Model Builder](https://github.com/kaskr/adcomp), both of which have built-in facilities for Laplace approximation.  For fixed effects you can use something like

```
library("skellam")
library("bbmle")
```

Reparameterize `dskellam(x, lambda1, lambda2)` to a form that is essentially location (geometric mean lambda=`gmlambda`=`sqrt(lambda1*lambda2)`) and shape (difference in lambdas: `ldiff=sqrt(lambda1/lambda2)` (so that `lambda1=gmlambda*ldiff`, `lambda2=gmlambda/ldiff`).

```
 dskellam2 <- function(x, gmlambda, ldiff, log=FALSE) {
     dskellam(x,gmlambda*ldiff,gmlambda/ldiff,log=log)
 }
```

Then something like this should work:

```
 mle2(A~dskellam2(gmlambda=exp(logmu),ldiff=exp(logs), data=mydata,
      parameters=list(logmu~B+C+D),
      start=list(logmu=0,logs=0)))
```

... but it could take some fussing to make it work.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try that although I am a bit afraid of the "fussing" part.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an variant on @BenBolker's answer, parameterizing in terms of the mean and variance.

You could get something GLM-like if you write the log-likelihood as a function of the mean and variance, express the mean as a linear function of covariates, and use `optim()` to get the MLE and Hessian.

The mean is `mu1-mu2`, the variance is `mu1+mu2`. The two parameters can be written as functions of the mean and variance, ie:

```
mu1 <- (mn+va)/2
mu2 <- (va-mn)/2
```

The constraint is that `mu1` and `mu2` are positive. To achieve this, the mean of the Skellam must be less than the variance. This suggests to reparameterize the variance as:

```
va <- max(abs(mn)) + va_st
```

And treat `va_st` as the parameter to estimate.

Putting that all together:

```
library(skellam)
logL_Skellam <- function(pars, X, Y){
    mn <- X %*% pars[1:ncol(X)]
    va_st <- exp(pars[ncol(X)+1]) # constrain to be positive
    va <- max(abs(mn)) + va_st
    # convert to parameters of skellam
    mu1 <- (mn+va)/2
    mu2 <- (va-mn)/2
    # optim minimizes so return negative LL
    -sum(dskellam(Y, mu1, mu2, log=T)) 
}
```

Optimise:

```
# simulated data
set.seed(103)
npars <- 3
nobs <- 300
X <- cbind(1, matrix(rnorm(nobs*(npars-1)), nrow=nobs))
beta <- rnorm(npars)
va <- max(abs(X%*%beta)) + 3.3
Y <- rskellam(nobs, (X%*%beta+va)/2, (va-X%*%beta)/2)

# fit
fit <- optim(c(0,0,0,5), logL_Skellam, X=X, Y=Y, hessian=T)
```

Taking care that `optim` actually converges. The MLE and std. errors of the regression coefficients:

```
fit$par[1:npars] # MLE
sqrt(diag(solve(fit$hessian)))[1:npars] # std error
```

And I'll add that to include random effects, it may be possible to use MCMC with the parameterizations in either answer, with a prepackaged sampler like STAN or JAGS (you'd need to use the [ones trick](http://users.aims.ac.za/~mackay/BUGS/Manuals/Tricks.html#SpecifyingANewSamplingDistribution) in JAGS). The hardest part to this may be porting the Bessel function in the Skellam PMF.

Comment: Thanks very much too, I will try this as an alternative and keep you posted.